# Jquery click won't get called at second click after incrementing i

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am building a site that has multiple stages, each stage has a button that on click will slide the next page. The button id is incremented dynamically with a counter, but it works only the first time, the second time will not call the click function, here's the code. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
   <button id="request-btn-1" class="red-button">Submit</button>
   <button id="request-btn-2" class="red-button">Submit</button>
   <button id="request-btn-3" class="red-button">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
var i = 1;
var count = $('.progress .circle').length;
console.log(count)

$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');


$('#request-btn-'+i).click(function() {
     if(i < count) {
            $('#request-stage-'+i).animate({
                left: '-=1140px'
            });

            $('#request-stage-'+(i+1)).animate({
                left: '-=1140px',
            });



          $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
          $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');
          $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').addClass('active');


          i++;
     }
    console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: Provide html code.

Comment: @Kind user done

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you want to do here. You want to log specified `i` according to the clicked element?

Comment: no, each time that the button is pressed, the page changes. a second button will be in the second page with the same id  but last number #request-btn- i. It works only for the first button and not the 2nd and third.

Comment: Do you have three separate pages or do you just change the content of a single page each time?

Comment: I change the content of each page

Comment: `count == 0` so `i = 1; ... if(i < count)` never will be evaluated. `i` is compared to `count` which relies on `$('.progress .circle').length` which you don't even have to your HTML code so we can see what it is and what it is doing. Don't expect people to guess what your code looks like and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery every time you are trying to add dynamicly an element, in this example a `button`, you need to add every listener back.
 At the beginning of your page ( `$(document).ready(function(){});`) Jquery add listener to every element in the page. It won't add more if you don't add them yourself. That's your problem.
You should consider having a button with a class you call when you want the `click` event to fire and a data attribute with your variable `i` in it. This way you will always have a listener on your button and you can save your variable in a safe place.

Comment: Where in the code provided do you see anything being added dynamically?

Comment: Well you i change. do you have a listener on every #request-btn-{your i} ?

Comment: And also, i don't see your code being in a loop. So your `i` is incremented one time that's it.

Comment: I tried to put in a loop, but it increments til the end straight away without need to click the button. How should I place the loop?

Comment: You should place the loop right after the `console.log(count)`, this way you will add listener to every button,

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads and your code runs, the click event is set on the element with the "request-btn-1" id, because i = 1 at that time.

So the first button's click event will keep working, but you haven't set any event on the other buttons and simply changing the value of "i" afterward can't change that.

You could set a click event on each button or like Nicolas said have a single button with an attribute of which you can change the value accordingly.